# Repeat an Action after specified second for specified time WindowForm C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm creating an auto function. I try to repeat an action for specified time. every time it takes a specified second that was given before.
How could i do that?

Comment: Please add more details, and code, to this question. It's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.6.2)

Comment: We should wait until more details are added, rather than post a link-only answer (even if it is to the documentation and less susceptible to link rot)